# How can I render a single column table with an array of objects using dataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a single column table that displays 10 results per page using datatables 1.9.4. The table is being populated by the dataTable ajax method. I can render one value per row but I will need to be able to render multiple values per row. (Think 1 row = 1 array in the json object.)

**How can I take an array of objects and render that array of objects into a single column?**

I've read up on [column rendering](http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) and [object arrays](http://www.media4u101.se/fobo-lift-template-demo/datatables/1.9.0/examples/ajax/objects.html). I'm having no luck.

e.g.

A row, once rendered, would look like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="email@email.com" class="mail">Email Product</a> <!-- this would come from product_email -->
        <h3><a href="#">Product1</a></h3> <!-- this would come from product_name -->
        <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, a, similique, fugit, ratione facere eius mollitia quo illo quos minus laborum suscipit vel nesciunt totam debitis? Nihil, rerum non sed.</p> <!-- this would come from product_description -->
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's what my data looks like (trimmed down):

```
{
    data: [
        {
            product_email: "email@email.com",
            product_name: "Product1",
            priduct_description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, a, similique, fugit, ratione facere eius mollitia quo illo quos minus laborum suscipit vel nesciunt totam debitis? Nihil, rerum non sed."
        },
        {
            product_email: "email@email.com",
            product_name: "Product2",
            priduct_description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, a, similique, fugit, ratione facere eius mollitia quo illo quos minus laborum suscipit vel nesciunt totam debitis? Nihil, rerum non sed."
        },
        {
            product_email: "email@email.com",
            product_name: "Product3",
            priduct_description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi, a, similique, fugit, ratione facere eius mollitia quo illo quos minus laborum suscipit vel nesciunt totam debitis? Nihil, rerum non sed."
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my call to dataTables

```
this.$el.find('table').dataTable({
    sDom: '<"top">rt<"bottom"<"showing"i><"product-length"l><"product-pagination unlist horizontal"p>><"clear">',
    sPaginationType: 'full_numbers',
    oLanguage: {
        oPaginate: {
            sFirst: '<<',
            sLast: '>>',
            sNext: '>',
            sPrevious: '<'
        }
    },
    bProcessing: true,
    bServerSide: true,
    sAjaxSource: 'products.php',
    /*columns: [
        { data: '[]' }
    ],*/
    fnServerData: function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        console.log(sSource, aoData, fnCallback);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello @Dennis , if you just initialize the datatable in the normal way... `$('#example').dataTable({"ajax": 'products.php'} );` ....did it draw the table correctly??

Comment: @RobertRozas Nope, it yells at me: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined `. I think it's yelling at me because it's expecting only an array, not an array of objects.

Comment: And this way: `$('#yourTableID').dataTable({"ajax": 'products.php'});` ....and remember, your table have to have a `thead` and a `tbody` in order to work properly with dataTables :)

Comment: @RobertRozas Still yelling at me :(. Are you having luck with array of objects? If so mat I please see your structure of data?

Comment: Your structure is matching with this sample: http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html ...i use dataTables in other way: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/Aw7pr/

Comment: @RobertRozas Yeah it's very similiar (just different names) the difference I'm seeing is that they are rendering a single value into the cell. I need to place a certain value from the array into a certain location in the cell (see html example output). I figured http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html would help, but I'm not having any luck with it.

Comment: Let me give you a full example based on your data...just wait a bit, i'm working on the jsfiddle

Comment: Your code is served sir xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Tabla").html("<thead><tr><td>Email</td><td>Name</td><td>Action</td></tr></thead><tbody></tbody>");
   $("#Tabla").dataTable({
     "aaData": arreglo,
     "aoColumns": [

      { "mData": "product_email" },
      { "mData": "product_name" },
      {
        "mData": null,
        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
         var nombre =  full.product_email ;
         var a2 = '<h3><a href="#">'+full.product_name+'</a></h3>';
         var desc = '<p class="description">'+full.priduct_description+'</d>';
        return '<a href="'+nombre+'" class="mail">Email Product</a> ' + a2 + desc;
      }
    }
                  ],
        "bDestroy": true
        }).fnDraw();   

});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/3kPVT/4/

Comment: This is very awesome! I did notice some things that were different between mine and yours, one being naming. I also had my array in the json file named "data" rather than "aaData." Thanks you very much for your help Robert.

Comment: No problem @DennisMartinez, it's been years using dataTables, so i know a few more tricks...feel free to ask anytime :)